# unique differentiable atlas making $F$ diffeomorphims

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $F:M\to N$ be a bijective mapping. If $M$ is a topological space, then $N$ admits a unique topology making $F$ a homeomorphism; it is easy prove that this topology could be:
$$T_N=\Big\{F(U):U\text{ is open in }M\Big\}$$
If $\mathfrak{A}_M=\{(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)\}$ is a differentiable atlas in $M$, we can show that $\mathfrak{A}_N=\{(V_\alpha,\psi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in A}$ constitutes a differentiable atlas in $N$; with:
$$V_\alpha = F(U_\alpha)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \psi_\alpha=\varphi_\alpha \circ F^{-1}$$
for any $\alpha \in A$.

*How I can prove that $\mathfrak{A}_N$ is the unique differentiable atlas on $N$ that makes $F$ diffeomorphism?*

If $I$ suppose $(W,\phi)$ local chart in $N$ such that $V_\alpha\cap W\ne \phi$ for some $\alpha \in A$, and I prove that $W$ and $V$ are compatibles, this implies that $\mathfrak{A}_N$ is unique by this way?

Many thanks!

Comment: What you need to show is that if $(W, \phi)$ is a chart on $N$ such that $\phi \circ F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, then $\phi$ is compatible with $\mathfrak{A}_N$ (which means $\phi$ is a member of the maximal atlas generated by $\mathfrak{A}_N$; i.e. is part of the same smooth structure).

Comment: Usually: $T_N=\{U\subseteq N\mid F^{-1}(U)\,\text{is open in}\,M\}$; otherwise $F$ is only open and bijective! Check it. ;)